# How to add a new CSS class to a Link Badge if the value is 0?

Tags: 7

I'm using the small module [Link Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_badges) to display a badge with the amount of flagged nodes next to a link to the View in question. It works great and I've styled the badge to my needs. This is the current HTML code:

```
<a class="menu__link menu__link link-badge-wrapper">
  <span class="link-badge-text">My View</span>
  <span class="link-badge-badge-wrapper">
    <span class="link-badge link-badge-menu_badges_execute_view">0</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Now, I'd like to display the badge a little bit differently (other colors etc.) when the value is 0. I thought about doing this by adding a new CSS class `link-badge-zero` to the value.

```
<a class="menu__link menu__link link-badge-wrapper">
  <span class="link-badge-text">My View</span>
  <span class="link-badge-badge-wrapper">
    <span class="link-badge link-badge-zero link-badge-menu_badges_execute_view">0</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ramis Wachtler at Stack Overflow, I got the following JQuery code:

```
if($(".link-badge").text() == "0"){
    $(".link-badge").addClass("link-badge-zero");
}
```

Possible easier solutions are always welcome.